# C two-way list deleting items

Tags: c, list

I have a problem. The code below creates a two-way looped list. When I want to delete an item of specyfic key value, everything goes right. The problem comes when I want to add an item after deleting another one. It just doesn't appear when I display the list. Do you have any ideas why?

```
    #include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <vector>
#include <stdlib.h>


struct List
{
        int key;
        double val1, val2, val3;
        struct List *next, *prev;
}*element, *temp, *head;

bool ifrepeat = false,ifdelete;

void AddOne(struct List *&head1, int x)
{
    List *tmp = head1;

    if (head1 != NULL)
    {
        do
        {
            if (head1->key == x)
            {
                ifrepeat = true;
            }
            head1 = head1->next;
        } while (head1 != tmp);
    }
    if (ifrepeat)
    {
        printf("Podana wartosc klucza juz istnieje!\n");
        ifrepeat = false;
    }
    else
    {

        head1 = tmp;
        if (head1 == NULL)
        {

            head1 = (struct List*)malloc(sizeof(struct List));
            head1->key = x;
            head1->val1 = 1 + (rand() % 1000);
            head1->val2 = 1 + rand() % 1000;
            head1->val3 = 1 + rand() % 1000;
            head1->next = head1;
            head1->prev = head1;

        }
        else
        {
            if (element == NULL)
            {
                element = (struct List*)malloc(sizeof(struct List));
                element->key = x;
                head->next = element;
                element->prev = head1;
                element->next = head1;
                head1->prev = element;
                temp = element;
            }

            else
            {
                element = (struct List*)malloc(sizeof(struct List));
                element->key = x;
                temp->next = element;
                element->prev = temp;
                element->next = head1;
                head1->prev = element;
                temp = element;
            }
        }
    }
}

void ShowBegin(struct List *head)

{
    if (head == NULL)
        printf("Lista jest pusta!");
    else
    {
        struct List *temphead;

        temphead = head;
        printf("%d ", head->key);
        head = head->next;
        while (head != temphead)
        {
            printf("%d ", head->key);
            head = head->next;
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

void AddMany(struct List *&head1, int x)
{
    AddOne(head, 10+(rand()%1000)*(rand()%1000));
    int tmpkey;
    List *tmp = head1;






    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
    {
        tmpkey = 10 + (rand() % 100)*(rand() % 1000);
        while (head1 != tmp)
        {
            while (head->key == tmpkey)
            {
                tmpkey = 10 + (rand() % 100)*(rand() % 1000);
                head1 = tmp;
            }
            head1 = head1->next;
        }

            AddOne(head, tmpkey);
            head1 = tmp;
            head1 = head1->next;


    }



}

void Sort(struct List *&head1)
{
    int max;
    List *maxPos,*tmp;

    maxPos = head1;
    max = head1->key;

    while (true)
    {
        head1 = head1->next;
        if (head1->key > max)
        {
            tmp = head1;
            head1 = maxPos;
            maxPos = tmp;
            max = maxPos->key;
            head1 = head;
        }

    }


}

void CreateList()
{
    head = NULL;
    element = NULL;
    temp = NULL;
}

void Delete(struct List *&head1, int x)
{

    struct List *temphead;

    temphead = head1;

    if (head == NULL)
    {
        printf("Lista jest pusta!\n");
        return;
    }
    else
    {



        head1 = head1->next;

        if (head1 == temphead)
        {
            if (head1->key == x)
            {
                free(head1);
                head1 = NULL;
                ifdelete = true;
            }
            else
                ifdelete = false;

        }
        else
        {
            while (head1 != temphead)
            {
                if (head1->key == x)
                {


                    List *temp;
                    temp = head1;
                    head1->prev->next = head1->next;
                    head1->next->prev = head1->prev;
                    head1 = head1->next;
                    while (head1 != temphead)
                    {

                    }

                    free(temp);
                    ifdelete = true;
                    break;

                }
                else
                    ifdelete = false;



                head1 = head1->next;
            }


        }
        if (!ifdelete)
        {
            printf("Element o podanym kluczu nie istnieje!\n");

        }
    }
}

void ShowEnd(struct List *&head)
{
    if (head == NULL)
        printf("Lista jest pusta!");
    else
    {
        struct List *temphead;

        temphead = head;

        head = head->prev;
        while (head != temphead)
        {
            printf("%d ", head->key);
            head = head->prev;
        }
        printf("%d", temphead->key);
        printf("\n");
    }
}

void DeleteAll(struct List *&head)
{
    free(head);
    head = NULL;
}



int main()
{
    int X=1000, k1=5, k2=2, k3=10, k4=-1;

    /*FILE* plik = fopen("inlab02.txt", "r");
    if (plik == NULL)
        return -257;
    fscanf(plik, "%d %d %d %d %d", &X, &k1, &k2, &k3, &k4);
    fclose(plik);*/

    srand(time(NULL));

    clock_t begin, end;
    double time_spent;
    begin = clock();

    CreateList();
    Delete(head, k1);
    ShowBegin(head);
    AddMany(head, 10);
    AddOne(head, k2);
    Delete(head, k2);

    AddOne(head, k4);

    //Delete(head, k4);
    ShowBegin(head);
    //ShowEnd(head);
    //DeleteAll(head);
    end = clock();
    time_spent = (double)(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf("Program wykonal obliczenia w %f", time_spent);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your code contains extraneous blank lines at random. You will burn in hell for that.

Comment: @PatrykNaklicki Seems you did not give the full code, it still shows compilation error.

Comment: It's copied from another site, I just changed it quickly so it does what I want it to. The problem appeard when I try to delete something - I'm trying to figure it out for sereval hours...

Comment: There is no more code - It's everything

Comment: @PatrykNaklicki uf! You would kill our several hours! If you do not give us a complete code, how can we test it and find your problem?

Comment: This code is complete, I don't know why it won't compile for you

Comment: @PatrykNaklicki Is it compiling in your pc? You are using `fscanf()`, `printf()`, `malloc` etc. functions in your code, where are the header files for them? Remember, WE WOULD NOT DO YOUR HOME WORK, okay? So, compile it, try it yourself first, if you stuck anywhere, then google it, then bring all things to us. People would eagerly help you.

Comment: @manetsus yes, I compile it on my PC. I changed the code a little, added malloc header (my PC compile malloc without that header). I am working on this code for 7 or 8 hours, I've googled everything and still delete function doesn't work properly. It's my first time when I ask for help - I've never done this before